# How to use external type definitions as interfaces, not as types

Tags: typescript, swagger, openapi

In my Next.js web app, I’m importing my Swagger/OpenAPI types into `global.d.ts` with:

```
type ApiDefinitions = import('types/swagger').definitions
```

…and then I can simplify the use of that type in my app with:

```
type User = ApiDefinitions['User']
```

But what if I want to use `interface User` instead of `type User`?

This doesn’t work because it seems to define `User` as `any`:

```
interface User extends ApiDefinitions['User'] {}
```

(Produces error: `Type error: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'User'`)

### Update

See [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-external-type-definitions-as-interfaces-not-as-types-1iljdw?file=/src/index.tsx) with example, it gives same error:

[image: CodeSandbox screenshot]

Comment: An interface [can extend type, no problem.](https://tsplay.dev/wOJnpW) Can you try to recreate the error in a https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: @AlexWayne - Or preferably with code in the question (so the question is complete here on-site). (Also, the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) is a bit lighter-weight than codesandbox for simple TypeScript examples.)

Comment: I can't reproduce this error either.

Comment: See the CodeSandbox I added to the question, hope that helps!

Comment: @jcalz Can you see the error in the CodeSandbox?

Comment: I see [this in the TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbAYBN), which is definitely has a bunch of errors including the one you're talking about.  There is no such type as `ApiDefinitions.UserOne` or `ApiDefinitions.UserTwo` so you're getting all kinds of bonkers stuff happening.  Your type is just `any` because of that, and your interface is just `{}` because of that.  Neither are correct (e.g., no complaint about missing `email` property) and I'm not sure why you prefer one over the other.

Comment: The real solution is to refer to your types correctly; you can't use dot notation to index into types; you have to use [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpgZpN), or if you really want to use dot notation you need to repackage your interface as a namespace like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAjkQW).  I'm happy to write up an answer but the question title "How to use external type definitions as interfaces, not as types" isn't really applicable.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to focus on the actual issue (that `ApiDefinitions.User` is not, in fact, working)?

Comment: @jcalz I updated the question and CodeSandbox; the problem remains even with the ApiDefinitions['User'] notation.

Comment: You can't write `interface UserTwo extends ApiDefinitions["UserTwo"] {}`, that's invalid syntax and it results in a TS error.  Interfaces can only extend named types, not arbitrary type expressions.  I think CodeSandbox must be doing a pretty bad job of showing you the errors your code has, and you should probably use something like the TS Playground instead.  Anyway, if you look at [my suggested approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpgZpN), you can see that I named a `U2` type to be an intermediary. I could write *this* up as an answer, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to keep using types:

```
type User = ApiDefinitions.User & {
   customField: unknown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the User interface as an actual interface, that's "importing" the User interface from the namespace ApiDefinitions, no?

Similar to how we can use `import("module")` to import the module's types as a namespace, we can use `import` to also import a type from a namespace:

```
import User = ApiDefinitions.User;
```

Wack syntax but it is reasonable. This is kind of like `use`/`using` in most languages.

You might also want:

```
import ApiDefinitions = import("types/swagger").definitions;
```

instead.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBGBLAIhAZu46ALugPbBRIDeAsAFBINIQAeMJAToUvoROzgmQBVKHyp1Gk7gBMAXEmABXMACM+AbgmMAvnV2066MG05IRYgLyoM2PAWJkoAOnPtNB2jz4DESAKLMvMDSENKuTIEQwRThNPSMoJDyUITs+ADm7vp08I5ciqLs8gFBIWGFSFZxkuhySAAMADRaDIkQ8gBEKiQqHc202upAA)